# Netbeans doesn't load modules for regular users

Tags: updates, netbeans

I wanted to install the updates on Netbeans7.4 but I couldn't as a regular user so I opened netbeans with sudo and it worked. After that, I can't open netbeans as a regular user, just with sudo. That splash screen appears, tries to read the module storage and just disappears without opening netbeans or a error message. I tried to open netbeans through the terminal to see whether a error appears, but nothing, when the splash screen disappears a new prompt occurs without any error message. I even tried to change the owner and group of the whole /usr/local/netbeans7.4/ directory but without any success.

What did I wrong and can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

I've just encountered exactly the same with Netbeans 8.0.1 (updating by running as sudo)

Changing the owner and group of some files in ~/.cache did the trick

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<group> ~/.cache/netbeans
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the owner (and may be the group) of ~/.netbeans/ directory and ~/.cache/netbeans directory as well.

```
sudo chown -R <user>:<group> ~/.netbeans
sudo chown -R <user>:<group> ~/.cache/netbeans
```