# net beans 8.1 not running only until reading modules

Tags: software-installation, netbeans

I have this in my terminal for checking

```
martin@martin:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There is 1 choice for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 
martin@martin:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Still my netbeans 8.1 is not starting up it is only starting up until reading modules and I dont know what is the error.

Also I added

`netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"`

In netbeans.conf As it was an accepted in a post but it didnt work for me.

I already tried uninstalling and installing a couple of times but it still didnt work.

I am out of idea right now and I hope some one will point me to the right direction

UPDATE

```
martin@martin:~$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_131
```

tried to run

```
martin@martin:~$ sudo chown -R martin:martin ~/.cache/netbeans
[sudo] password for martin: 
martin@martin:~$
```

from this [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429809/netbeans-doesnt-load-modules-for-regular-users) still didnt work

[paste bin of messages.log](https://pastebin.com/8PEFa5SV)

Comment: (not a solution) netbeans always felt very underdeveloped (atleast for linux), and lacks lots of features available in eclipse and intellijidea.

Comment: you are suggesting to use eclipse instead? it is not a solution indeed.. But i want to run this one in netbeans since it is what i have right now can you think of any way for this to work?because i tried to uninstall and install but it didnt work

Comment: So, [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750514/netbeans-not-all-requested-modules-can-be-enabled) didn't work? What error message do you get?

Comment: yes that was the answer I got it from.. no error it just didnt start it just close in the part where it says `reading module storage`

Comment: are you trying the correct architecture? Also, it seems theres a [related bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=247637)

Comment: what do you mean correct architecture? how can i check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67157/discussion-between-sirajus-salekin-and-guradio).